# How to get old version row in hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm using Hbase and i'm trying to retreive old version number with shell and take the result and put it back in hbase table as the most recent ?

```
 scan 'TEST',{ VERSIONS => 2}
```

In case when I have done some errors and want to back up old version using timestamp.

Any idea  how to do this with shell or the easiest way possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Scan*** : specify version count

```
 scan 'mytable', {VERSIONS => 2}
```

***get***

```
get 'mytable', 'myrowkey', {COLUMN => 'cf:mycol', VERSIONS => 2}
```

to get a specific time you can use get with time stamp as shown below

```
get 'mytable', 'myrowkey', {COLUMN => 'cf:mycol', VERSIONS => 2, TIMESTAMP => 123242131 }
```

Between range of time stamps you want to query then go with `TimeStampFilter`

#### Note :

AFAIK From shell, there is no shortcut to put back your old values rather by seeing old values from the shell again you need to give put command on the same row.

Comment: Yes thank you, so i need to get the row version i want and to put it back in hbase explicitly, I think i can do a workflow with NIFI that get in hbase the row version i want and put it back in hbase using the get and put processors